# Ajax Jquery variable with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is there any way I can use json and jquery to retrieve a variable and use it?

Ie what I want to do is use jquery to call a php script, query mysql and then return this variable to use on my original page.

ie

$( "#result" ).load( "query.php");

and then be able to echo this result on my calling page.

I know that the div with the id #result will be populated with the data but I want to be able to echo it as a value so my jquery progress bar will change

```
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: <?php echo"$light"; ?>
});
```

});

Here I'm just using a php query on load but I want to have it dynamically change every 30seconds without having to refresh.

Comment: I'm not sure what u want. U want to refresh data every 30 seconds? Or update ur progressbar? When you use ajax you only can get an event when it comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$.ajax("query.php").done(function(data) {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: data})
});
```

(Untested code, but should work in principle.)

Comment: I try this and the ajax returns the data because I can stick it into an alert but it does not change the value of the progress bar. 

any other ideas? I can use math.floor to generate a random number and this works :/

Comment: Can you show us your current code? You can post it either here in a comment or update your answer, if you like.